# How to repair JSON that won't parse?

Tags: javascript, .net, json, parsing

I cannot understand the parsing error below. You can use https://jsonformatter.org/ to get errors:

```
{"lookup": "defaultStatelessKieSession",
    "commands": [
        "insert": {
            "object": {
                "myteam.hello_kie_server_2.SMS": {
                    "sendMessage" :  true
                }
            },
            "disconnected": false,
            "out-identifier": "Message",
            "return-object": true,
            "entry-point": "DEFAULT"
        },    
        { "fire-all-rules" :{} }


     ]
}
```

parsing problem is :

```
Parse error on line 3:
... [
        "insert": {
            "ob
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'
```

but I don't understand which "{" or "[".

Comment: This part `"insert": ` is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element "insert" is a json object and must be put into {}

```
{
    "lookup": "defaultStatelessKieSession",
    "commands": [
        {
            "insert": {
                "object": {
                    "myteam.hello_kie_server_2.SMS": {
                        "sendMessage": true
                    }
                },
                "disconnected": false,
                "out-identifier": "Message",
                "return-object": true,
                "entry-point": "DEFAULT"
            }
        },
        {
            "fire-all-rules": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`key-value` pair objects are invalids within Arrays, so you need to remove this part `"insert":`

```
{
  "lookup": "defaultStatelessKieSession",
  "commands": [{
      "object": {
        "myteam.hello_kie_server_2.SMS": {
          "sendMessage": true
        }
      },
      "disconnected": false,
      "out-identifier": "Message",
      "return-object": true,
      "entry-point": "DEFAULT"
    },
    {
      "fire-all-rules": {}
    }
  ]
}
```